# Macro taking a class body, eliminating explicit new operator?

Tags: scala, macros, new-operator, scala-2.10

I never liked the `new` operator in Scala, particularly for DSLs. The workarounds for constructing objects *without* `new` are usually quite ugly. For instance, if you import `scala.actors.Actor._`, you have `actor { ... }`, but inside the body you are not having access to `this: Actor`, so there is all sorts of pseudo instance methods in that object, too, like `receive`, `react`, `self`, etc.

With Scala 2.10 macros, I wonder if there is a chance to get the following working?

```
object Button {
  def apply(body: ? ): Button = macro applyImpl(body)
  def applyImpl(c: Context)(body: c.Expr[ ? ]): c.Expr[Button] = ?
}
trait Button {
  def text: String
  def text_=(s: String): Unit
  def doSomething(): Unit
}

Button {
  text = "test"
  doSomething()
}
```

As an additional challenge, what happens if `doSomething` is `protected`?

Comment: should the macro implement the unimplemented methods in the Button trait? Or are we to assume they have already been implemented in some subclass of Button?

Comment: I imagine the macro instantiates an implementation of the trait, like an anonymous class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this will work, since

```
{
   text = "test"
   doSomething()
}
```

won't compile, as there is no `text` and no `doSomething()` method outside of the `Button` trait. Macros can currently only work on expressions that have already been typechecked.

Comment: Correct. But in future versions of Scala we plan to experiment with macros that don't need to have their arguments typechecked.

Comment: I wanted to write "can currently only work", but then I thought it's not really relevant now.

Comment: Ok... so I take Eugene's comment to mean I cannot expect any further answer on this, and close the question?